# Laravel production: The file "/home/forge/default/storage/app/geoip.mmdb" does not exist or is not readable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following error when moving my site to production.

```
The file "/home/forge/default/storage/app/geoip.mmdb" does not exist or is not readable. (View: /home/forge/default/resources/views/layouts/extra_scripts.blade.php) (View: /home/forge/default/resources/views/layouts/extra_scripts.blade.php) (View: /home/forge/default/resources/views/layouts/extra_scripts.blade.php)
```

It is related with this package: [Torann/laravel-geoip](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip)

The default laravel .gitignore file ignores the storage folder and therefore the file is missing in production:

```
/vendor
/node_modules
/public/storage
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json
.env
```

My question is: Should I remove /public/storage from .gitignore? Is it a good practice to include this file in my project? Is there another way to make this package work?

Comment: Just copy it up manually, or don't keep it in storage/app/geoip.mmdb

Comment: So the best practice would be to keep /public/storage in my .gitignore file and change the location of the geoip.mmdb, right?

Comment: Set permission to 777 of storage folder.

Comment: I do not want/like to change the permission of any folder to 777

Comment: Do you know any preferred location to store this kind of files in Laravel? public folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding after skimming the documentation, you should be able to just run `php artisan geoip:update` and it will re-create the database for you. No need to keep it in your git repo.

> Optimization Tip: When using the database option I don't like having the downloaded database in my git repository, so I have my deploy system run the `geoip:update` during the build process before it's deployed to the servers.

http://lyften.com/projects/laravel-geoip/doc/services.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, nice research, it works perfectly.